# Is it possible to create an "all users" installer for an Office 2010 add-in using InstallShield LE (VS2012)?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, installshield, office-addins

I created an installer for my Office 2010 add-in using the InstallShield LE product bundled with VS2012. Wasn't exactly the most pleasant experience.

Anyway, it installs the add-in under the users account. I'd like to have the option to install for "all users". I can't see how to do this in InstallShield LE, but I'm unclear whether I just can't find the option, or it's not supported in that crippleware version, or simply not possible at all.

Any pointers welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do change my installer from a per-user installer to an all-users installer by changing the registry keys being created/set.

Still can't find a way to give the user a choice at the time of installation, though.

Comment: You have to buy a more expensive version of Installshield to do that. LE is extremely simple.